# mod_rewrite problems: negation

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache

I'm trying to understand mod_rewrite better and have one particular problem I think I need to get my head round first.

I am rewriting `http://www.somesite.tld/a/b/c` to `index.php?path=a/b/c` using the following

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index.php)(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L]
```

An equivalent rewrite would, in this case, be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L]
```

- This does not work without the `RewriteCond` -- path=index.php would be the result without specifically ignoring files or saying 'not index.php'. **Why is this?**
- Also, what is the `?!` and `?:` syntax that I sometimes see used? I do not understand the use of the `?` when it is not prefixed by anything.
- And why, in the first RewriteRule above, do the second pair of brackets return a match for $1?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(?= ...)` and `(?! ...)` is special syntax in Perl regular expressions and in [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt), which is the regex library that Apache uses. They are, respectively, positive and negative lookahead assertions: they match an empty string if the text after it matches or does not match the content in the brackets.

They are non-capturing, so they don't define any `$n` (it would be pointless, since they match an empty string). `(?: ...)` is also non-capturing, it is used to group subexpressions.

Your first rule should work in `.htaccess` (but not in a virtual host configuration file), though it would be more correct to write it as

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$)(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

Perhaps another rule is interacting with it. You can check what exactly is being matched and rewritten with [`RewriteLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and [`RewriteLogLevel`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel).

Comment: Glad that I asked this question, I didn't know of lookahead assertions but they seem very useful.

Answer (score -1):

"!" means negation. Like  a = 1 (a is equal one) a != 1 (a is not equal one);
"f" means file. So if you use together with "!", like "!-f" would be something "file does not exist". the links below may help you better:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess.html
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/
http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: This does not explain why the above rewrites work the way they do, or the lookahead `?!` syntax.

Comment: And so, how to write a negative condition ? The 2 or 3 generic htaccess docs are not an adapted answer